# Building emacs 29 on openSUSE: `configure` cannot find json library despite it being installed

Tags: emacs, opensuse, gcc, libraries, configure

Im currently trying to build emacs 29.0.90 from source. I've installed every version and permutation of json-devel, json-c, libjsoncpp, etc on the repositories, and even built, tested, and installed json-c from source, and still, running `./configure --with-json` gives an error saying it can't find the `json` library. I've tried explicitly setting the LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS variables to the location where the json library is, and no luck with that either. I can't figure it out for the life of me. I was able to build it on Ubuntu, but not here. Does anyone have any ideas about what else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

It was `libjansson-devel`, not any permutation of `json-c`, that was needed.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).